# Custom field type - cardinality unlimited - multi column - radios to select default/primary

Tags: 10

I created a custom field for the [CRM](https://drupal.org/project/crm) project to handle telephone numbers. It has multiple properties. I am having trouble getting primary to work; I want to be able to mark one of the telephone numbers as primary.

The [CRMTelephoneWidget](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/crm/-/blob/1.0.x/modules/crm_field/src/Plugin/Field/FieldWidget/CRMTelephoneWidget.php?ref_type=heads) displays a radio as the primary property, and the value is saved. Still, more than one item can be primary because each has a different form name.

```php
$element['primary'] = [
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#options' => [$delta => $this->t('Primary')],
  '#title' => $this->t('Primary'),
  '#default_value' => $items[$delta]->primary ?? NULL,
];
```

I manually set the form name, as follows. Only one radio can be selected, but the value is not saved.

```php
$element['primary'] = [
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#options' => [$delta => $this->t('Primary')],
  '#title' => $this->t('Primary'),
  '#default_value' => $items[$delta]->primary ?? NULL,
  '#attributes' => ['name' => 'telephones[primary]'],
];
```

Any help or advice will be greatly appreciated!

| Name | Type | Example |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Phone | string | 555-555-5555 |
| Extension | string | 123 |
| Type | string | phone, fax, mobile (entity reference to config) |
| Location | string | home, work, billing (entity reference to config) |
| Primary | boolean |  |
| Mobile Provider | string | t_mobile |

Comment: By grouping the radios the submitted data is no longer in the structure of the field deltas. Put the method `public function massageFormValues(array $values, array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)` in the widget class and check $values for both cases. Then you know what to do. Please post the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the interesting part of `massageFormValues`. I can pull the primary value from the user input.

```php
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function massageFormValues(array $values, array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $primary = 0;
  foreach($values as $delta => $value) {
    if (isset($value['primary'])) {
      $primary = $value['primary'];
    }
  }
  foreach ($values as $delta => $value) {
    $values[$delta]['primary'] = FALSE;
    if ($values[$delta]['_original_delta'] == $primary) {
      $values[$delta]['primary'] = TRUE;
    }
  }
  return $values;
}
```

```php
    $field_name = $this->fieldDefinition->getName();
    $element['primary'] = [
      '#type' => 'radio',
      '#return_value' => $delta,
      '#title' => $this->t('Primary'),
      '#default_value' => $items[$delta]->primary ? $delta : NULL,
      '#attributes' => [
        'id' => $field_name . '-primary-' . $delta,
      ],
      '#parents' => [$field_name, 0, 'primary'],
    ];
```

Comment: Add something like `'#parents' => ['radios', $this->fieldDefinition->getName()],` to the radios so that the submitted data depends on the field name, if someone wants to add the field type multiple times to a content type. BTW you can get the submitted value of the radios element with getValue():  `$form_state->getValue(['radios', $this->fieldDefinition->getName()]);`

Comment: "The submitted value 1 in the Primary element is not allowed." The does not work. Shouldn't it be [$this->fieldDefinition->getName(), 'primary'] ?

Comment: I don't think this works, the field doesn't accept `primary` submitted as field delta. The validation error is probably low-level Form API validation, the `radios` don't know about the other options. Try to use single `radio` elements which have as #return_value the field delta.

Comment: But you can submit it in the first field delta `0`. I've posted an answer with single radio elements

Comment: From @BinaryAlchemist: *There were problems when re-ordering the elements. I added a hidden element to track the original delta.* - Great, I think the version in your answer is the best solution. I can now delete my answer. BTW there is already an `_original_delta` in $values, you could try this instead of the hidden element.

Comment: I was able to use `_original_delta`. I have also replicated this pattern in the CRMEmailWidget.